# Problema con adivina palabra en c++

Tags: c++

Muy buenos días, tengo un asunto, el cual es que quiero hacer el juego de adivina la palabra, pero tengo un ligero detalle, el cual es que, a la hora de ingresar una letra para leer ir adivinando, me contesta que esta mal al menos que sea en orden acomodado, por ejemplo: "Hola", si pongo "Hola", letra por letra consecutivamente lo detecta y me dice que voy describiendo correctamente, pero si por ejemplo pongo una t, y fallo y luego pongo una h, aunque la h, este en la palabra hola, me dice que esta mal, se que es porque no estoy poniendo las palabras en orden continuo, espero puedan ilustrarme con su sabiduría compañeros expertos, saludos a todos.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void word(string);
char secreta[]={'h','o','l','a'};
void search(char);
int vidas=4;
int aux=4;

int main() {
    char letra;
    cout<<"Palabra: ";
    word(secreta);

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Juego iniciado"<<endl;
    cout<<"Digite una letra para adivinar"<<endl;
    search(letra);
    return 0;
}

void word(string secreta){

    for(int i=0; i<secreta.size(); i++){
        cout<<"*";
    }

}
void search(char letra){

    int arrSize = sizeof(secreta)/sizeof(secreta[0]);

    for(int i=0; i<arrSize; i++){
        cout<<"Numero de vidas: "<<aux--<<endl;
        cin>>letra;

        if(letra==secreta[i]){
            cout<<"Letra adivinada "<<secreta[i]<<" - Siguiente: "<<endl;
        }else{
            cout<<"Fallaste "<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En tu metodo search,  el for es incorrecto porque recorres desde el indice 0 hasta la longitud de la palabra secreta. Por ejemplo: cuando i=0 e ingresas la "t", entonces, la comparas con la letra de secreta[0] y falla. La segunda vez ingreso la "h" pero i=1, entonces la "h" la comparas con secreta[1] y es el motivo que nunca vas a encontrar las letras. Cada letra siempre debes compararla  desde el inidice 0 de la palabra secreta. Por lo tanto pon un while antes del for y mueve las dos lineas siguientes al for hacia arriba de for.

Comment: No entendi mucho lo ultimo, pero si entendí porque estoy mal, agradezco tu apoyo compañero